# tablespace error restoring a table in Mariadb

Tags: mariadb, restore

Trying to restore a martiadb table backupd uyp to ibd format. using the MAriadb documentation.

I dropped the table, then recreated from the frm file.

THen when I try to import the dataspace, if I don't discard the tablespace I get:

> Error SQL query: ALTER TABLE `tbl_bm` IMPORT TABLESPACE MySQL said:
> Documentation
> #1813 - Tablespace for table 'bm/tbl_bm' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT

If I do discard the tablespace, I get:

> Error SQL query: ALTER TABLE `tbl_bm` IMPORT TABLESPACE MySQL said:
> Documentation
> #1030 - Got error 194 "Tablespace is missing for a table" from storage engine InnoDB

Advice please.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this issue today.
I have tried to restore a database from backup server using mysql data files (frm,ibd)

I have created the database in the destination server.
I have discarded the tablespace for each table that I wanted to import.
I have stopped the mysql server.
I have placed the ibd and frm files in the /var/lib/mysql/{db}/ folder.
I have started the mysql server
I have tried to import the tablespace but run into this error.

After checking in /var/log/mysql/error.log it turned out that I have not copied some ibd files from backup folder.
The error stated:

> [ERROR] InnoDB: Trying to import a tablespace, but could not open the
> tablespace file

I stopped the server.
I copied again the missing files and checked the permissions.
I started the server and reimported the tablespace.